# Python: How to create a loop to change longitude data

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, coordinates

I am using python 3.6 to map precipitation data onto a continent. The problem is that the data I have has longitude values ranging from 0 to 360 and I need to get the data to -180 to 180 in order to map it. I need to create a loop that  states if the longitude is > 180 then the new longitude= longitude-360.
About my data: I want to loop through 56 years. x is where I have all my longitude values stored

Here is what I have so far:

```
lon=[]
for n in range(0,56):
    lon=x[n]
    if lon > 180:
        lon=lon-360
np.save('filename',lon)
```

Does this look right? Are there any examples that are similar to my problem? Thanks!

Comment: You never store the `lon` back to the array.

Comment: noticed you attached `numpy` then  using `np.where` ?

Comment: I am new to python. How would I do this? @EugeneSh.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking but I am using numpy because my data comes from a numpy file. So earlier on in my code I open the numpy file containing all data, adjust the longitude, and then re-save my file as a numpy file. @Wen

Comment: Add both `np.where` and loop method , recommend @MaxU's answer also, loop always be considered the last chose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this :

```
x=[100,200,400,500,100,181,179]
lon=[]
for n in x:
    if n > 180:
        lon.append(n-360)
    else:
        lon.append(n)
```

by using `np.where`:

```
x=np.asarray(x)
np.where(x >180,x-360,x)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Numpy as @Wen has already recommended:

```
In [16]: lon = np.array([100,200,400,500,100,181,179])

In [17]: lon
Out[17]: array([100, 200, 400, 500, 100, 181, 179])

In [18]: lon = np.where(lon > 180, lon-360, lon)

In [19]: lon
Out[19]: array([ 100, -160,   40,  140,  100, -179,  179])
```

alternatively we can do it this way:

```
In [30]: lon[lon>180] -= 360

In [31]: lon
Out[31]: array([ 100, -160,   40,  140,  100, -179,  179])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
x=[100,200,400,500,100,181,179]
lon = [y if (y <= 180) else (y - 360)  for y in x ]
```